# Retrieve Firebase dictionary data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database structured like this:

```
results: {
  A: [
    {data}
  ],
  B: [
    {data}
  ],
  C: [
    {data}
  ],
  ....
}
```

It is a dictionary of values sorted alphabetically.

My question is, **what would be the best way to retrieve this data in swift?**

Comment: Did you check out the Firebase Guide [Working With Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) which also covers sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the most common practice for retrieving Firebase data is to cast the snapshot's value to a Swift `Dictionary` like this:

```
let myRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("results")
myRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() {
        // handle data not found
        return
    }

    // data found
    let myData = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]    // the key is almost always a String 

    // extracting data from the dictionary
    let A = myData["A"] as! [String: Any]
    let dataInA = A["anyChildOfA"] as! Double

    // ...

})
```

It doesn't really matter if the data is sorted or not on Firebase, retrieval would be of the same complexity

**Update**

You can simply loop over all the alphabets to extract the data:

```
var extractedData = [[String: Any]]()     // array of Swift Dictionary
for c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters {
    let temp = myData[String(c)] as! [String: Any]

    extractedData.append(temp);
}
```

`extractedData[0]` would be the data in `A`, `extractedData[25]` would be the data in `Z`. That, of course, is assuming you have a child for each letter.

Comment: would i have to hard code the 'let A = myData['A']" for each letter of the alphabet?

Comment: Updated the answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct to present "data":

```
struct Data {
   ...
}
```

Create a wrapper:

```
struct DataWrapper {
     let data: [Data]
}
```

Then, create a new model:

```
struct ModelName {
    results: [DataWrapper]
}
```